# Python - Text input within a Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, user-input, tkinter-canvas

I want to create a userinput box for integers inside a canvas I created with Tkinter. How I would go about doing this?

```
def gamescreen():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="gamescreen.gif")
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", buttonclick_gamescreen)
    canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
    canvas.create_image(1, 1, image = photo, anchor = NW)
    e1 = Entry(canvas)
    e2 = Entry(canvas)
    game1 = PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
    canvas.create_image(30, 65, image = game1, anchor = NW)
    canvas.create_window(window = e1, x=10, y=10)
    canvas.create_window(window = e2 , x=400, y=10)    
    canvas.update()
    window.mainloop()
```

This is what I currently have but a entry box doesn't appear anywhere on the canvas. I know this probably isn't the most efficient way to create a game in python but I'm not familiar with any other way.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I have updated the code with the suggestions provided. I now have an issue with

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

This is occurring at the lines below

```
canvas.create_window(window = e1, x=10, y=10)
canvas.create_window(window = e2, x=400, y=10)
```

EDIT: Okay I figured out what was wrong, I had to remove the x= and y= and just have the coordinates by themselves. The entry boxes now appear.

Comment: Just based on your code, if you're looking to make a game you should really check out Pygame (http://pygame.org).

Comment: or why not use gtk? http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for replies but this is for an assessment at high school so I wasn't sure if I could learn how to use Pygame or gtk in time.

Comment: And it's just a simple maths learning game with no flashy graphics or animations so I didn't think it would be suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I did some more reading up on what a tuple actually is and I was able to fix the error.

Just had to remove the x= and y= so that the coordinates of the window are by themselves.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [create_window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method) to place a widget within a canvas.

```
e1 = Entry(canvas)
canvas.create_window(400,10,window=e1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I seem to be running into another error. This time it displays 
"IndexError: tuple index out of range"
I searched up the error message here and on google but didn't find anything related. :/

Comment: Please fix your answer.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: fixed. Thanks for letting me know about the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment your e1 and e2. You have to use the .pack() feature.

```
e1.pack()
e2.pack()
```

This should get it to go on the screen, the rest is up to you!

EDIT: Also, shouldn't it be canvas.mainloop()? Is window defined or is canvas?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was able to make the input box appear but now seems to replace the images that were placed onto the canvas, I'll keep working on it to find a solution.
I have window and canvas defined in the main subroutine

Comment: pack almost certainly won't do what the OP wants -- it doesn't place the entry _on_ the canvas. It will create the canvas to shrink to fit the entry widget, and the entry widget won't scroll along with the contents of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the mistake in the order of the parameters:

It should be:

```
textentry = Entry(canvas)
canvas.create_window(600, 50, window=textentry, height=50, width=1000)
```

where the first two parameters specify the point around, which the entire textbox will center itself.
Height and width are to set the height and width of the textbox.

The window is to specify the entry.